# In jQuery, how do I select nodes (with a string only selector) "starting" from the current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside the following loop, I'd like to select any arbitrary node, relative to the current element `$this`. The selector is a string, stored inside the `data-qty` field:

```
$('[data-add-product][data-qty]').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
        qtySelector = $this.data('qty');

  // Here, i want to use the string selector "qty"
  // to select any arbitrary node, relative to the current element
  $this.parent().find(qtySelector); // not a good solution

});
```

I can't use `parent()` on `$this` because doing that will "constraint" the selector to be a descendant of the parent (of the current node).

An example:

```
<div>
  <a data-add-product="123546" data-qty=":parent .qty">Add to cart</a>
  <span class="qty">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand your question, you want to get the value `3` on `<span class="qty">3</span>`, starting from `  data-qty=":parent .qty"` ??

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The purpose is to allowe generic selectors because i do not know the structure in advance.

Comment: For what reason do you need to put the jQuery selector in the HTML at all? Surely the HTML isn't that likely to change. Just use `$(this).siblings('.qty')`...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe it's used in 2 or 3 points, where the html structure is quite different and you need to duplicate the JS code to do the same thing.

Comment: In that case look to create a generic, repeated HTML structure around that functionality in the UI.

Comment: I agree @RoryMcCrossan this would be best practice. But sometimes simply put...you can't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-add-product][data-qty]').forEach(el=>
  {
  let el_target = el.dataset.qty
      .split(' ')
      .reduce((r,s)=>
        {
        if (s===':parent') return r.parentNode
        if (s[0]=== '.')   return r.querySelector(s)
        },el)
  console.log( el_target.textContent, `\n`, el_target )
  })
```

```html
<div>
  <a data-add-product="123546" data-qty=":parent .qty">Add to cart</a>
  <span class="qty">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you i’ll try, that is exactly what i mean, allow generic and fexible selctors because i don’t know html structure.